# How to add collection within document + angularfire2 + angular5

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, angular5, angularfire2

I want to add a collection within a document, I searched a lot over google but I haven't found any proper resolution.
Even searched firebase documentation but no results for my query.

I have tried different ways to add a collection to a document, below is an example of my code.

```
let tmpObj = {
  title: vm.pageTitle,
  creationDate: dt.getTime()
};
this.db.collection("pages").doc("page_"+this.bookId).collection("Test").add(tmpObj);
```

Also, I even tried

```
let mainCollection = this.db.collection("pages").doc("page_"+ this.bookId).collection("test").valueChanges();
let subcollection = mainCollection.push(tmpObj);
// This is also not working for me
```

In the above code **db** is **public db: AngularFirestore**
Please find the attached screenshot to see where I want to add the collection (highlighted it).

Structure I need is **Collection -> Document -> Collection**

[image]

Comment: You are getting any console errors?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I am not getting any errors

Comment: Can you `subscribe` to `subcollection`  and see what result you are getting?

Comment: your code should have worked, add a `("Test").add(tmpObj).catch()` and check for any errors. also you need to check your firestore rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code sufficed my needs and with this code now I can create as many nested collections within each documents.

```
tmpObj = {
    title: vm.pageTitle,
    desc: description,
    creationDate: dt.getTime()
  }

this.db.collection('pages').doc("pages_"+ this.bookId).collection<any>("AllPages").doc("page_"+ dt.getTime()).set({tmpObj})
.then(function() {
    console.log("Pages Created successfully!");
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

please try :

```
this.db.collection(`pages/page_${this.bookId}/Test`).add(tmpOb);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this template

```
await this.db.collection('mainCollectionName').doc("mainDocID").set(obj);
await this.db.doc('mainCollectionName/mainDocID').collection('subCollectionName').doc('subDocumentID').set(subCollectionObj);
```